# Unauthorized error when joining existing cluster using kubeadm join command

Tags: kubernetes, raspbian, kubeadm

I have a couple of Raspberry Pis which I am trying to use to set up a Kubernetes cluster for learning purposes.

I've set up a control-plane on a master node successfully. However, when I try to join a worker node to the cluster I get "timed out waiting for the condition / error uploading crisocket" message.

Here is my join command (as printed by the master node):

```
kubeadm join 192.168.0.4:6443 --token rbebts.cj9zl03jor3nt09m     --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:dfd705812b44887726abbdc7e91187c76a407498c1d1b73ebc1aa81c9486848c
```

I tried running it with -v9 option and I see that it is successfully fetching cluster configMap using the provided token (which tells me that the token I use is valid and it is not the root cause of the problem):

```
I0916 13:44:44.248364    9187 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.19.1 (linux/arm) kubernetes/206bcad" -H "Authorization: Bearer rbebts.cj9zl03jor3nt09m" 'https://192.168.0.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kube-proxy?timeout=10s'
I0916 13:44:44.256611    9187 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://192.168.0.4:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/configmaps/kube-proxy?timeout=10s 200 OK in 8 milliseconds
```

However, further I see a lot of authorization failures:

```
I0916 13:44:53.146479    9187 round_trippers.go:443] GET https://192.168.0.4:6443/api/v1/nodes/node-1?timeout=10s 401 Unauthorized in 8 milliseconds
I0916 13:44:53.146559    9187 round_trippers.go:449] Response Headers:
I0916 13:44:53.146618    9187 round_trippers.go:452]     Cache-Control: no-cache, private
I0916 13:44:53.146675    9187 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Type: application/json
I0916 13:44:53.146729    9187 round_trippers.go:452]     Content-Length: 129
I0916 13:44:53.146782    9187 round_trippers.go:452]     Date: Wed, 16 Sep 2020 17:44:53 GMT
I0916 13:44:53.147654    9187 request.go:1097] Response Body: {"kind":"Status","apiVersion":"v1","metadata":{},"status":"Failure","message":"Unauthorized","reason":"Unauthorized","code":401}
I0916 13:44:53.637836    9187 round_trippers.go:423] curl -k -v -XGET  -H "Accept: application/json, */*" -H "User-Agent: kubeadm/v1.19.1 (linux/arm) kubernetes/206bcad" 'https://192.168.0.4:6443/api/v1/nodes/node-1?timeout=10s'
```

Looking at the curl command I see that Bearer token is missing (which could explain 401 responses).

I've just started learning about Kubernetes and I am not sure if I am doing something wrong here and how to resolve this.

Some info about my setup:

```
kubeadm version: &version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"19", GitVersion:"v1.19.1", GitCommit:"206bcadf021e76c27513500ca24182692aabd17e", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-09-09T11:24:31Z", GoVersion:"go1.15", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/arm"}


docker 18.09.1

Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to enable `--v=10` for "join" and observe the API call failures.
this might give a better indication of what is going on.

Also you can execute [`kubeadm reset`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/) command.
`kubeadm reset` is responsible for cleaning up a node local file system from files that were created using the `kubeadm init` or `kubeadm join` commands. For control-plane nodes `reset` also removes the local stacked etcd member of this node from the etcd cluster and also removes this node's information from the kubeadm `ClusterStatus` object. `ClusterStatus` is a kubeadm managed Kubernetes API object that holds a list of kube-apiserver endpoints.

Take a look: [kubeadm-join](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1587), [kubeadm-reset-issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/1587).

Comment: Thank you very much @Malgorzata! 
Running kubeadm reset on the worker node resolved my problem. I was able to join it to the cluster after that (for some reason I thought kubeadm reset applies to master node only). I still do not know what was the root cause of my problem, but it is resolved now. Thanks a lot for your time!